# py2neo V4 no longer supports "watch" import

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have a python program that uses the py2neo V3 library. It contains the following sections of code (this is not a complete program):

```
import io
from py2neo import watch

def initWatch(self, ):
    self.httpCapturer = io.StringIO()
    watch("neo4j.http",out=self.httpCapturer)
    self.boltCapturer = io.StringIO()
    watch("neo4j.bolt",out=self.boltCapturer)

def closeWatch(self, ):
    self.httpCapturer.close()
    self.boltCapturer.close()

def logWatch(self, ):
    httpWatch = self.httpCapturer.getvalue()
    boltWatch = self.boltCapturer.getvalue()
```

This works in V3 but no longer works in V4. When running this in V4 I get the following error:

cannot import name 'watch' from 'py2neo'

I can't find any reference to this in the V4 documentation so I'm wondering how to implement this functionality.  I'm not looking for specific code just some direction, i.e. is there a new command in V4 that provides the "watch" functionality or is this no longer included?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out...  The py2neo v4 package wraps the official neo4j python driver and that's where the watch class is so the import is now...

from neo4j.util import watch